# Load file from GitHub in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, github

I have written a PowerShell script which loads a json file and performs certain function on it. I am using:

```
$json = Get-Content 'C:\Users\Documents\test.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

to load the file which works. But I want to store both these files in a git hub repository. How can I access the json file path once I store both the files in the same directory in a GitHub repository?

I am new to using GitHub so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you need to install **git** on your PC and issue commands to it with PowerShell. Read on basic commands like `git clone`, `add`, `commit`, `push` and you'll do fine.

Comment: Thanks  , but how will i reference the path of test.json file in my powershell script after performing the steps you mentioned. i know how to store the file in github , but i need to reference the file in a powershell script

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with a remote path, you can use the webclient to download the file as a string and convert it using the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet:

```
$jsonPath = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaypat/documents/master/test.json'

$json = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($jsonPath) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: Thank Martin ! I will try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Joey True. I tend to use webclient since the chocolatey installer also uses it....

Answer (score 0):

You might need to either use the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) or commit and push using git. For the latter you should do something like the following from the local git repository:

```
git add test.json
git commit -m "Message for what changes you've made"
git pull
git push origin master
```

It'd be really helpful if you first read and understood what git is and how it works. Then you'd be ablt to use github seamlessly. Here is a great interactive tutorial for it: https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Comment: Thanks @ayush , but how will i reference the path of test.json file in my powershell script after performing the steps you mentioned. i know how to store the file in github , but i need to reference the file in a powershell script

Comment: Why not locally clone the repository using `git clone <url-of-repo>` and then use the command you're currently using `$json = Get-Content 'C:\Users\Documents\test.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json ` and perform actions on the files. When you're done, execute the steps in my answer.

Comment: beacuse this code is supposed to be executed from github ,as this will go in jenkins and run from there.

Comment: @JayPat You could clone the repository and work with the local file as mentioned by ayushgp. You could also use a remote path as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using path binding to reference the file

$path = join-path $psscriptroot "env.json"

This sources to the directory where all the files are loaded.